# retrieve GSM CellId,mnc,mcc using java script

Tags: java, javascript, gsm, mobile-website, cellid

i am developing a mobile web application. i want to find the user current location even when device GPS is off. after some google search i found that opencellid database we can retrieve the latitude and longitude of mobile by passing cellId,mnc,mcc to the opencellId.

is there any way to get the cellId,mnc,mcc by using java script or java program?please suggest any others ways if possible. This is a mobile web application.

Thanks and Regards,
vinay

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get telephony information using a Web Application. You need to implement specific Apps running on mobile.

Comment: I want to do the same. Is there an api for that. But the information that i want is MCC MNC LAC CID on the basis of latt and long