# How can i determine the MCC and MNC devices through javascript?

Tags: javascript, gsm

I need identify user visiting the my site. 
I want using determination of cellular towers.

How can i determine the **MCC** and **MNC** devices through javascript?

Comment: Please improve this question so others can help you out. See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp, I think question is full

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve GSM CellId,mnc,mcc using java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615030/retrieve-gsm-cellid-mnc-mcc-using-java-script)

Comment: @vp_arth, yes, but the question needs a complete answer

Comment: Complete answer - you can't to get it with javascript.

Comment: @vp_arth, For example can using "Deep packet inspection"